# 22.04 upgrade from 21.10 - external monitor no longer seen

Tags: upgrade, multiple-monitors

I upgraded from 21.10 on my Lenovo model 20TJ-S12Q00 laptop to 22.04 LTS. After the upgrade the system no longer sees the external monitor. Something was asked during the upgrade about providing a password that would be used later to enable something but I can't remember more of what this was nor was I asked later about providing the password I entered. I'm not sure if this has something to do with the hardward\e being disabled perhaps or not. What can I do to get the 22.04 to see the external monitor?
Thanks for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI (unless you're dual-booting with Windows 11).

Answer (score 0):

During the reboot I missed the very very small, icon sized, box that was too small for me to see the "Enroll MOK" option which would have allowed the UEFI to provide use of third party drivers.
I ended up later as root doing "apt install nvidia-driver-510". This again informed me that I needed to provide a password for the UEFI and that I would need to provide it upon reboot to do the "Enroll MOK" which would allow the third party driver to be used.
This met my needs and I now have both internal and external monitors working.